# iOS Adding a device in the developer portal

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add a device (iPhone 5) by the UUID, but the the loader never stop loading. I am not doing anything different then I normally do, but I feel like the loader will never stop since I have been waiting for a long while now.

Is there something wrong with my account or whatever or...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reload the page and try again

Comment: Done it 3 times allready

Comment: The best way to add a device is using the Organizer in XCode

Comment: Use safari and not chrome, at least that seemed to be my issue.

Comment: @rckoenes Are you kidding me.. (4 hours further) and this fixed my problem... Add your comment as answer and I'll accept

Comment: its not only the privisioning portal. Try browsing the reference library for a while using opera and you will go mad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use safari and not chrome, at least that seemed to be my issue.

Somehow the Apple developers site is having some issues with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cut out the browser from this task completely you can have a look at Cupertino, part of the Nomad-cli toolset. Amazing work from @mattt

https://github.com/nomad/cupertino

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out!